# Запуск таймера при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: java, android

Есть такой код с таймером.

```
    mTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    new CountDownTimer(500000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimer.setText("Осталось"+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimer.setText("");
        }
    }.start();
```

Он запускается автоматически после старта приложения. Как сделать, чтобы он запускался после нажатия кнопки?

Comment: выставить запуск кода по нажатию на кнопку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто разместите этот код в слушателе кликов кнопки:

```
mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1;
mTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

mButton.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {

     new CountDownTimer(500000, 1000) {
       @Override
       public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTimer.setText("Осталось"+millisUntilFinished / 1000);
       }

       @Override
       public void onFinish() {
        mTimer.setText("");
       }
    }.start();  
  }
});
```

При более сложной логике, вы можете вынести код таймера в отдельный метод и в слушателе кликов кнопки (метод `onClick()`) вызывать нужные вам методы для организации требуемой логики.